# Difference of meaning between present perfect and past simple

Tags: past-tense

I was just wondering if you could use past simple instead of present perfect if you know for sure that the event won't happen even the event took place not long  ago

The parcel **has not been** delivered (there is a possibility that it will happen in the future) but if I am sure it won't happen can I use the past simple to imply that is definitive and therefore belongs to the past. Can present perfect implies that it can be also definitive (won't change)

Answer (score 2):

Full credit for this answer to @Kate Bunting!

Yes. If it has not been delivered [yet], you are still waiting for it. If it was not delivered, you have probably given it up for lost, unless you are referring to a particular time (it wasn't delivered today, but may come tomorrow).

Answer (score 0):

The present perfect talks about the past and the present. The past simple talks about the past.

It has not been delivered. It has not been delivered yet.

We use **the** **present perfect tense** with **today** and **this week, this month** etc.  It has not been delivered today. It has not been delivered this week/this month/this year.

We use **the past simple** tense with yesterday, a few minutes ago, five minutes ago, a few days ago, last week, last month, last year, the day before yesterday, on Sunday, on Thursday etc.

It was delivered five minutes ago. It was not delivered last month.

It has been delivered this morning. It is still morning.

It was delivered this morning. It is afternoon or evening.

In American English the past simple is used with 'yet'.

It was not delivered yet.